# Any way to "forward" an IM from jabberd2 to users on Cisco XMPP?

Tags: linux, cisco, xmpp, jabber

I use a `jabberd2` MUC to monitor server status from Graylog and Nagios. The helpdesk guys would like to be able to join the MUC, however they are on Windows (I'm on Linux) and have a Cisco jabber client of some kind that doesn't appear to be configurable enough to point it at a second XMPP server. Is there any way to maybe "forward" messages from the Linux XMPP server to the Cisco XMPP server?

**Update** (added SRV records):

```
_jabber._tcp.jabber.my.lan.net.           IN SRV   5 0 5269   jabber.my.lan.net.
_xmpp-server._tcp.jabber.my.lan.net.      IN SRV   5 0 5269   jabber.my.lan.net.
_xmpp-client._tcp.jabber.my.lan.net.      IN SRV   5 0 5222   jabber.my.lan.net.
_jabber._tcp.conference.my.lan.net.       IN SRV   5 0 5269   jabber.my.lan.net.
_xmpp-server._tcp.conference.my.lan.net.  IN SRV   5 0 5269   jabber.my.lan.net.
_xmpp-client._tcp.conference.my.lan.net.  IN SRV   5 0 5222   jabber.my.lan.net.
```

Comment: XMPP federation is supposed to do this; they should be able to join the MUC by giving the full name (e.g., room@muc-server-name). Does this not work? If so, did you set up e.g., SRV records? Is federation turned on? (You can probably configure federation with only a limited list of domains).

Comment: I'll give the full name a try. I added SRV records -- pasted in update above. Not sure about "federation" I'll have to look. Thanks for the clues.

Comment: Curious if you got it working? If so, you can (and are encouraged to) answer your own question.

Comment: Not working. Not sure about "federation". We "Reset" the Cisco client on the windows desktop and the only options offered for configuring a connection were `automatic`, `Cisco IM and Presence`, `Webex Messenger` and `Cisco Communication Manager 9 or later`. On automatic, an error came up about finding the server - maybe related to SRV records and the user being on a different subnet..dunno. Then tried configuring CIMP with `username@jabber.my.lan.net` and I saw the client trying to connect on port 8443, which is not the XMPP port. If it's supposed to work, I'll have to google for more info.